# what implications have redefining *_before_type_cast in an activerecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Let's say I want to redefine a method in a model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accesor :model_attr

  def model_attr
    'redefined'
  end
end
```

When I access it directly, it works as it is supposed to, but when I call it from the view:

```
f.text_field :model_attr
```

It doesn't. But this still works:

```
f.text_field :model_attr, value: @model.model_attr
```

So I had to dig into Rails code:

```
def text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
  Tags::TextField.new(object_name, method, self, options).render
end
```

to

```
class TextField < Base # :nodoc:
  def render
    options = @options.stringify_keys
    options["size"] = options["maxlength"] unless options.key?("size")
    options["type"] ||= field_type
    options["value"] = options.fetch("value") { value_before_type_cast(object) } unless field_type == "file"
    options["value"] &&= ERB::Util.html_escape(options["value"])
    add_default_name_and_id(options)
    tag("input", options)
  end
```

and

```
    def value_before_type_cast(object)
      unless object.nil?
        method_before_type_cast = @method_name + "_before_type_cast"

        object.respond_to?(method_before_type_cast) ?
          object.send(method_before_type_cast) :
          value(object)
      end
    end
```

Okay, so it looks like `text_field` is not accessing the attribute directly, but rather appending `_before_type_cast`. I've [read the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast.html), but still do not understand why this is necessary for `#text_field`?  I can do this, and it works:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accesor :model_atr

  def model_attr
    'redefined'
  end

  def model_attr_before_type_cast
    model_attr
  end
end
```

If I redefine both methods, can I get in trouble somehow in the future? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for using `*_before_type_cast` is found on the description of this [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/7b5ed66122873eebb773a6418f3a94d946cc4f8c) :

> Added use of *_before_type_cast for all input and text fields. This is helpful for getting "100,000" back on a integer-based 
>    +  validation where the value would normally be "100".